# C - Socket Programming - my server can't bind to address

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm writing a simple UDP echo server and for some reason the server doesn't continue executing after the `bind()` function.
here's the code:

```
/*Required Headers*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#define MAXLINE 100

void HandleClient(int comm_fd);
void Die (const char * msg)
{
   perror(msg);
   exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    char str[100];
    int listen_fd, comm_fd,n;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: ./HelloITServer <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        Die("Falied to create socket");
    };

    printf ("%d" ,listen_fd);
    memset( &servaddr,0, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    if (bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0)
    { 
       Die("Failed to bind socket to address");
    }
    else {
        printf ("\n binded successfully");
    }

//    if (listen(listen_fd, 10) < 0)
//    {
//          Die("Failed to listen on server socket");
//    }


    while(1) 
    {

//        if ((comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
//              Die("Failed to accept client connection");
//          }

//        HandleClient (comm_fd);
        memset (&cliaddr,0,sizeof(cliaddr));
        len = sizeof (cliaddr);
        n = recvfrom (listen_fd,str,MAXLINE,0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,&len);

        sendto (listen_fd, str, n, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, len);
    }
}


void HandleClient(int comm_fd)
{

  char str[MAXLINE];
  int received;

  memset(str, 0, MAXLINE);
  received  =  read(comm_fd,str,MAXLINE);
  if (received < 0) {
      Die("Failed to receive from client");
   }
  while(received > 0)
  {

     printf("Echoing back - %s",str);

     if ( write(comm_fd, str, received) != received){
         Die("Failed to send bytes to client");
     }
    memset(str, 0, MAXLINE);
    received =   read(comm_fd,str,MAXLINE);
    if (received < 0) {
      Die("Failed to receive from client");
   }


 }       
}
```

it just doesn't print out the statement after executing it neither do it execute the die () function !
the client code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd,n;
    char sendline[100];
    char recvline[101];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: ./HelloClient <server_ip> <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof servaddr);

    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port= htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&(servaddr.sin_addr));

    //connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

//    while(1)
//    {
//        bzero( sendline, 100);
//        bzero( recvline, 100);
//        fgets(sendline,100,stdin); /*stdin = 0 , for standard input */
// 
//        write(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline)+1);
//        read(sockfd,recvline,100);
//        printf("%s",recvline);
//    }
    while (1) {
        bzero( sendline, 100);
        bzero( recvline, 100);
        fgets(sendline, 100, stdin);
        sendto(sockfd, sendline, strlen (sendline), 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, (socklen_t) sizeof (servaddr));
        n = recvfrom (sockfd, recvline, 100, 0, NULL, NULL);
        printf("%d",n);
        recvline[n]=0;
        printf ("%s",recvline);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `bind` hangs indefinitely? Or are you saying that it terminates your program without any output? Or something else?

Comment: hangs indefinitely, the program keeps running but doesn't show out any output other than the listen_fd

Comment: Perhaps another program or another instance of the same program is already bound to the port that you are attempting to bind to... is that possible?

Comment: I have changed the port and worked, thanks mate. but now still it does not echo back the input from and to the client, I will add the code for the client

Comment: @user1712638 - have you tried listening and accepting connections? By the way `SOCK_STREAM` isn't `UDP`. If you want `UDP` you should use `SOCK_DGRAM` or `SOCK_SEQPACKET`.

Comment: @alvits thanks, that was my stupid mistake !!!

Comment: have you tried `fflush(stdout)`?

Comment: I'm glad you got everything working now.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
printf ("\n binded successfully");
```

to this:

```
printf ("\n binded successfully\n");
```

(i.e., add an `\n` to the end). This will cause an `fflush` to be performed on standard output, so that the "success" output will actually be printed to the screen, and you can see that you've entered the while-loop and are waiting for a connection.

(Alternatively, you could add an explicit `fflush(stdout)` after the above statement, to flush standard output yourself. But it's good practice to send the newline, and you don't seem to have a reason for not doing so.)

Comment: I did that after a friend suggested it and didn't work

Comment: @user1712638: Define "didn't work". Also, note that this isn't just something-to-try; it's something that you really need to do, even if that's not your *only* problem.

Comment: ok, but there was something wrong with the code other than that so no output was printed